# How to skip last iteration of while loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This is my code:

```
System.out.println("Enter upper limit of range");
long u = in.nextLong(), x = 0, y = 1, z = x+y;
System.out.println("Fibonacci Series till " + u + " -");
System.out.print(x + " " + y + " " + z + " ");
while (z < u) {
    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = x + y;
    System.out.print(z + " ");
}
```

I want to skip the last iteration so that the last number of output does not go beyond the limit.

For example, if I initialise the value of `u` to `25`, then it will also print `34` which goes out of the limit.  Skipping the last iteration will not display the number `34`.

Comment: write u-- above while block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just print before you increment `z` to the next number in the Fibonacci sequence:

```
while (z < u) {
    System.out.print(z+" ");
    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = x + y;
}
```

With this change, the final iteration still would result in `z` being advanced to a value which is too high, and would fail the next iteration, but you would not be printing this number.

This refactor also takes care of another problem you had, namely not printing the first number in the Fibonacci sequence.  By placing the print statement *after* advancing the number, the initial value of `z` would never have a chance to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
while(z<u)
 {
    x=y;
    y=z;
    z=x+y;
    if (z < u) {
     System.out.print(z+" ");
    }
}
```

It's the simplest solution, assuming I got the question right...

Comment: This should work, but it has the possible downside of having to do an `if` check for each iteration of the loop.  For very large values (i.e. # of iterations) in the sequence, there could be a performance penalty.

Comment: you're probably right, though practically this overhead should be negligible, even for a large `u`

Answer (score 0):

```
while (...) {
   ...
   ...
   if (condition){
      continue; // which skips to the following iteration
      // or
      // break; // which just stops the loop from iterating
}
```

so the condition in your case could be `z<u`
or you can put the print itself in the if clause

Comment: it will print nothing - because the loop runs as long as `z < u` so the condition always evaluates to true

Comment: wrong. z is updated before the printing, but after entering the iteration. 
The solution that was suggested where you print first is better, true, but still - this solution is also right

Comment: True, that's what I suggested in my comment in the code.
The question was how to skip iteration - the direct answer, without getting into what he was meaning to do, is `continue`. 
In the case of **last iteration**, the answer is indeed `break`

Answer (score 0):

Print the current value first, then update z.

```
System.out.println("Enter upper limit of range");
long u=in.nextLong(),x=0,y=1,z=x+y;
System.out.println("Fibonacci Series till "+u+" -");
System.out.print(x+" "+y+" ");
while(z<u)
{
    System.out.print(z+" ");
    x=y;
    y=z;
    z=x+y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter upper limit of range");
long u = in.nextLong(), x = 0, y = 1, z = x+y;
System.out.println("Fibonacci Series till " + u + " -");
System.out.print(x + " " + y + " " + z + " ");

while (true) {
    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = x + y;
    if(z>u) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.print(z + " ");
}
```